# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (62)

Tags: mysql, macos, mac

На все запросы к MySQL выдает:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/tmp/mysql.sock' (62)

Перерыл все, ничего не помогает. Использую macOS Sierra.

Comment: Это проблема может быть с разрешением директории mysql.Я добавил решение на этот случай в свой ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Решение 1: Это проблема с разрешением `/usr/local/mysql` директории.**

**[Устранение проблем с разрешениями в Mac OS X](https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/ht2963)**

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql
./usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld stop
./usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld start
```

**Решение 2: Вероятно, потому, что MySQL установлен, но еще не запущен.**

Чтобы убедиться, что он запущен, откройте «Монитор активности» и в разделе «Все процессы» найдите и убедитесь, что вы видите процесс «mysqld».

Вы можете запустить его, установив «MySQL.prefPane».

Обычно я запускаю команду остановки и снова запускаю ее:

```
mysqld stop
mysql.server start
```

После в командной строке наберите `mysql -uroot -ppassword`

> (root и password это я к примеру,если у вас отличаются то вводите свой
>   )

если увидите строки на подобие "Welcom to the mysql monitore ..." значит все работает корректно.

[Install MySQL on Mac OS X](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.am/2009/08/install-mysql-on-mac-os-x.html): В самом конце показано как работать с ним после правильной установки

```
Вот команды запуска  и остановки  MySQL:

sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM restart
```

Comment: До этого пользовался MySQL, ошибки стал выдавать внезапно.
'mysqld stop' останавливает сервер, но mysql.server start не работает. 
Обращение к MySQL выдает ту же ошибку: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (62)

Comment: @MatveyKorepanov  Попробуйте так `mysqld start`