# Красивый и информативный вывод ошибок в браузер

Tags: php, обработка-ошибок

При возникновении ошибки в PHP (в частности при ошибках выполнения MySQL-запросов) некоторые сайты возвращают в браузер красиво оформленное сообщение с подробностями возникновения ошибки (имя файла, номер строки, выполняемый запрос)

Например вот такое решение:
[image: http://wowdes.pp.ua]

Как можно реализовать что то подобное?

Comment: Чаво ? Ошибку что ли инициализировать ?

Comment: Может это решение вам поможет ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671712/207445

Comment: Зачем вы хотите сделать свой сайт кривым?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить mysql c опцией  --socket=/path/to/socket - где /path/to/socket - несуществующий путь.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Что-то мне кажется что топикстартер хочет чтобы ошибки так оформлялись, а не получить точно такую же ошибку

Comment: @tutankhamun Именно так.

Comment: @tutankhamun  Так вопрос о том как показывать ошибки ? Тогда вопрос надо задавать под метками  `HTML`  и  `CSS`

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Это уже к топикстартеру. А о чем вопрос достаточно понятно написано в заголовке

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3):

На рабочем сайте так делать **НЕЛЬЗЯ** (это при том, что я не люблю пишущих капсом и делать категоричные заявления)

Такая картина свидетельствует только о том, что это **кривой сайт** и что на нем можно поискать проблемы с безопасностью (тут же и информативный инструмент прилагается).

Обязательно отключайте вывод ошибок в html. Ошибки должны быть записаны в лог и регулярно просматриваться. Если вы дорожите сайтом, то по количеству ошибок должна собираться статистика и при превышении некоторых порогов происходить рассылка админам, разработчикам и т. д.

Клиенту должно быть возвращено сообщение c извинениями и рекомендациями по дальнейшим действиям. Что-то вроде такого:

> Извините, произошла ошибка. В ближайшее время мы ее устраним. Вы
>   можете попробовать перезагрузить страницу позже. Если проблема не
>   будет устранена, позвоните нам +7 (555) 555-55-55 или напишите на
>   support@oursite.com.

Также для идентификации можно генерировать номер тикета и прилагать его к сообщению, чтобы потом разобраться какая часть логов относится к проблеме данного клиента. Это уже зависит от того, насколько вам важен каждый клиент и насколько техподдержка готова разбираться с каждым обращением.

Также если у вас серьезный сайт и есть реальная техподдержка с нормами реагирования, фраза *"В ближайшее время"* может быть заменена на *"Не позднее ..."*

Comment: [про вопрос-картинку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5305/178576)